# Homebrew trying to load removed packagaes on login

Tags: homebrew

Some time ago, I uninstalled PHP from my machine as it was no longer needed. I did so with `brew uninstall php@5.6` and `brew uninstall php`. However, after a few brew updates, I started getting an error message when starting my terminal:

```
Warning: Use php56 instead of deprecated homebrew/php/php56
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/core/php56"
```

What do I need to do in order to remove any remains of homebrew php from my system?

Comment: $ brew uninstall --force php@5.6 (https://mark.shropshires.net/blog/how-reinstall-homebrew-php-after-move-homebrewphp-homebrewcore)

Comment: still the same :/

Comment: This should help you out I hope: https://github.com/Homebrew/install    Referenced from this page:(https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/48792) Be sure to see this MASTER https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall